# Abstract Doctrine association mapping without discriminator (legacy DB)

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with a legacy database (that means no schema changes!) and I need to create a associations between the the Doctrine entities involved. I'll describe the data structure first and then explain what I've tried.

The database has a user table with various other tables also storing user related info. Eg:

`siteUser` has:

- contentId (PK)
- firstName
- lastName
- username
- password
- ...

and `siteUser` entities have metadata in this system which is along the lines of:

- metadataId (PK)
- title
- description
- keywords
- createDate
- publishDate
- contentId
- contentTable (discriminator)
- ...

Almost everything in the database can have Metadata by storing it's PK in the `metadata.contentId` field and the table name in the `metadata.contentTable` field. Note that `metadata.contentId` is not a foreign key, these must have been alien to the DBA as I'm yet to see a single one.

Users on the system can save information they find relevant to them so that they can come back to the system later and don't have to go hunting for the same information again.

This is done with content types called `conLink`, `conVideo`, `conLeaflet` stored as database entities (which have metadata).

For example a `conVideo` looks like this:

- contentId (PK)
- embedCode

The way users can store mark this information as being relevant to them is by the system storing it in a link table called `userSavedContent`:

- userSavedContentId (PK)
- userId
- metadataId

Note that `userSavedContent.userId` and `userSavedContent.metadataId` are also not foreign key constraints.

**THE APPROACH!**

I need to get user's saved content. In SQL this is no problem!

```sql
SELECT 
    metadata.title,
    conVideo.embedCode
FROM 
    userSavedContent
INNER JOIN 
    metadata ON userSavedContent.metadataId = metadata.metadataId
INNER JOIN 
    conVideo ON conVideo.contentId = metadata.contentId
WHERE userSavedContent.userId = 193745 
    AND metadata.contentTable = 'conVideo'
```

However doing this in Doctrine is more complicated because the value of `metadata.contentTable` could potentially be any of the `conLink`, `conVideo`, `conLeaflet` entities.

So my application is built using Symfony2 (and Doctrine) and I have models defined for all of the above entities.

In this `Metadata` is an abstract class with a discriminator on `metadata.contentTable`:

```php
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="metadata")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="contentTable", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
 *     {
 *         "conLink" = "MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata\ConLinkMetadata",
 *         "conVideo" = "MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata\ConVideoMetadata",
 *         "siteUser" = "MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata\SiteUserMetadata"
 *     }
 * )
 */
abstract class Metadata
```

The `ConVideoMetadata` class extends `Metadata` and adds a `content` property that associates the `ConVideo` entity to it:

```php
/**
 * @var ContentType $content
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(
 *     targetEntity="MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\ContentType\ConVideo",
 *     inversedBy="metadata",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contentId", referencedColumnName="contentId")
 */
protected $content;
```

Now the `userSavedContent` entity has `metadata` property to associated it to an item of metadata.

```php
/**
 * @var Metadata $metadata
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *     targetEntity="MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata",
 *     inversedBy="userSavedContent"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="metadataId")
 */
protected $metadata;
```

And finally the `siteUser` is related to `userSavedContent` by the following property on it's entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\UserSavedContent",
 *     mappedBy="siteUser",
 *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
 *     orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contentId", referencedColumnName="userId")
 */
private $userSavedContentItems;
```

**THE PROBLEM!**

In my `siteUserRepository` class I now need to query for a siteUser and all it's saved content items:

```php
    $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('s', 'm', 'usc', 'uscm', 'uscc')
        ->innerJoin('s.metadata', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('s.userSavedContentItems', 'usc')
        ->leftJoin('usc.metadata', 'uscm')
        ->leftJoin('uscm.content', 'uscc');

    return $builder;
```

This doesn't work!

`"[Semantical Error] Error: Class MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata has no association named content"`

This makes sense of course since `MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata` doesn't have the `content` property, it's child `MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata\ConVideoMetadata` is the one with that association. I thought Doctrine would have been able to work this out but apparently not.

So my question is:

- Is this approach very wrong? And if not what can I do to make that association/query work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this issue was to get Doctrine to eagerly fetch the concrete metadata->content entities. I could declare these explicitly but used Doctrine's `MetadataFactory` to get the Metadata entity's discriminator for the list of all possible content types.

```php
$metadataFactory = $this->getEntityManager()->getMetadataFactory();
$metadataMetadata = $metadataFactory->getMetadataFor('MyApp\Bundle\DataApiBundle\Entity\Metadata');

foreach ($metadataMetadata->discriminatorMap as $contentEntity) {
    $builder->getQuery()
        ->setFetchMode(
            $contentEntity,
            'content',
            ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER
        );
}
```